# State-space in simulink with one scalar input

Tags: simulink, state-space

I am using state-space block along with a mux in simulink. I am having two inputs so after passing through mux block I get a row vector. As state-space block accepts one scalar input so when a row vector is given as an input it doesn't work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First you should check the dimensions of your state space matrices A,B,C & D. If matrix B is of nx2 then one can use a mux; where n is the order of the system.